# How to delete file whose name begins with "--"?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, rm

I create a file named "`--address=16.187.249.27`" by accident, and try following methods to delete it, but no success:

```
$ rm "--address=16.187.249.27"
rm: unrecognized option '--address=16.187.249.27'
Try 'rm ./'--address=16.187.249.27'' to remove the file ‘--address=16.187.249.27’.
Try 'rm --help' for more information.

$ rm "\--address=16.187.249.27"
rm: cannot remove ‘\\--address=16.187.249.27’: No such file or directory
```

How to delete file whose name begins with "--"?

Comment: `rm -- yourfilename`

Comment: `rm` is also helpful enough to tell exactly what to do to delete yor file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a single instance of `--` to your command line means that everything that comes after is file names and not flag arguments. So this should do it:

```
rm -- --address=16.187.249.27
```

Answer (score 2):

from the man page

> NOTE
>        The rm command uses getopt(3) to parse its arguments, which allows it to accept the `--` option which will cause it to stop
>   processing flag options at that point.  This will allow the removal of
>   file names that begin with a dash (`-').
>
> ```
>  For example:
>        rm -- -filename
> ```
>
> The same behavior can be obtained by using an absolute or relative path reference.
>
> ```
>  For example:
>        rm /home/user/-filename
>        rm ./-filename
> ```

so you can delete by running

```
rm -- --address=16.187.249.27
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options do remove such a file:

```
rm ./--address\=16.187.249.27
rm "./--address=16.187.249.27"
rm './--address=16.187.249.27'
rm -- --address=16.187.249.27
find -maxdepth 1 -name "--address=16.187.249.27" -delete
```

Comment: The last one will recurse into subdirectories and also remove every file with that name that you may want to keep :-)

Comment: @EmilVikström fixed, thanks